# perform window.close() AFTER form data has been posted

Tags: forms, post, window

In developing a Punch-out shop for SAP users we would like the browser to close after the user clicks submit on the shopping cart.

We have to HTTP post our html form data to a target URL. If we use onSubmit ="window.close()" the JavaScript window.close() fires before the form is submitted and the form data is not posted.

Has anyone overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The best to answer is to get the page you are submitting to, to return a html page which closes it's self

```
<html>
  <body onload="window.close()">
  </body>
</html>
```

As a quick note most browsers will only let you close a window you have opened with window.open.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. We've been looking at opening a page and closing as you described. However. The url we are posting to is the client's SAP return URI, not a page on our website.